# set-aduser attribute for multiple users importing a csv file

Tags: powershell

i want to add the kerberos encryption attribute for many users. for that i have a csv file without header. all users are written with their samaccountnames in each row.
unfortunately it doesn't work. there is no error message and the attributes will not be set for the users. whats wrong with the code? what needs to be changed for the changes to be adopted?

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\user.csv" | foreach {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samaccountname -KerberosEncryptionType AES128,AES256}
```

Comment: Your example code appears to work for me in my test environment. After running it I can confirm that the `msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes` attribute is successfully updated on the user objects. How are you checking to confirm if the change was successful or not? (I'm using `Get-ADUser ExampleUsername -Properties "msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes`) Also, have you suppressed errors with `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"` somewhere else in your script (assuming there's more to it than the given example)?

Comment: it seems, there is a delay in the presentation. it seems to work for me now. can you help me with the code for an entire ou? not importing an csv, just set-aduser for an ou

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment made in the original question, here's how you'd process this for a given OU:

```
# Specify the OU you'd like to process here
$ou = "OU=Example Users,DC=contoso,DC=com"

# Search for users within that OU
# You can also specify the '-SearchScope Subtree' parameter if you want to get users recursively from child OUs
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -Filter *

# Pipe the users to the Set-ADUser cmdlet to make your changes
$users | Set-ADUser -KerberosEncryptionType AES128,AES256
```